# How to add an ngModel and formControlName together in an angular custom component?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngmodel, form-control

I want to make a custom component in angular .Sometimes i will use recative forms to call this component and sometimes without reactive components.

For that ,sometimes i will use formControlName and sometimes ngmodel.
The problem is that i can not add those two properties together in my custom component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tie-reactive-forms-throgh-wrapper-hfptmu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-wrapper%2Fdate-wrapper.component.html

[image: ngmodel and custom component together]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you're looking for is the ControlValueAccessor interface:
https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

If you implement this interface on your component, the methods of the interface will allow the component to work with both template driven and reactive forms (ngModel and formControl/formControlName). For clarity, you don't need ngModel or formControlName as Inputs on your component, this interface will cause this to be allowed.

Comment: Angular University has a detailed explanation on why and how to use ControlValueAccessor, it's worth checking it out! Link: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/

Comment: is there any example on the net so we can follow .What are saying is not clear .We need to add input eiter ngmodel or formcontrolname .I tried your solution by deleting the @input but it does not work.

Comment: Guide @LincolnAlves has added is very thorough and has a working example within it of a component that increments a number. Check it out - very detailed

Comment: it works like a sharme .Thanks @Plabee